# Using a VPN, how do I send UDP packets to, and receive broadcast packets from, the other network?

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, forwarding

I need to forward UDP packets through a VPN connection. Usually this is not supported when the destination address is the limited broadcast address or a network broadcast address. But the Wake-on-LAN protocol requires that the frame is sent to the broadcast address. The reason is that there is nothing that would resolve any target unicast IP address to the MAC address.

My setup consists of the following components: Windows 7 VPN client, Windows ISA server as RAS server.

- What is necessary to forward UDP packets to the corporate network?
- How could I receive broadcasts from the corporate network at my host?

Comment: If you want to do wake on LAN over a VPN you should re-word your question to focus on that, by asking how to route UDP packets instead of focusing on your real question you are falling in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Wake-on-LAN is one question I have focused here:http://superuser.com/questions/560187/how-to-wake-on-lan-through-vpn-router. But I need more than this as my second topic addresses: I want to receive broadcasts too.

Comment: @harper See my answer ... How to wake-on-LAN through VPN router http://superuser.com/questions/560187/how-to-wake-on-lan-through-vpn-router