# How to wake-on-LAN through VPN router

Tags: vpn, wake-on-lan, forwarding

I am working at home and want to wake a computer in the corporate network. I have a VPN connection from my Windows 7 PC to the ISA server that operates as RAS server.

Wake-on-LAN is based on UDP/IP and should be sent to the broadcast MAC address. When I try to send a packet to the network broadcast address at my PC it looks like it is not forwarded to the corporate network.

Is it possible to configure the VPN client and the ISA server so that wake-on-LAN packets go though?

**Edit**

For clarification I have some addresses:

- home PC VPN adapter address 192.168.1.93 [varies on RAS dial-in]
- wake-on-LAN PC 192.168.1.22
- ISA PC 192.168.1.1

I have some further addresses that should not care:

- ISA external address 83.26.4.139
- home PC LAN adapter address 192.168.73.10
- home PC NAT router address 192.168.73.1
- home PC NAT external address [varies on DSL connect]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a subnet division between your home IP over VPN and the destination. Your corporate network may not be forwarding WOL packets to the destination subnet. It is tricky to get WOL to work on subnetted networks.

Comment: The RAS Server assigned an IP address in the corporate subnet to my VPN session. And yes, it looks like broadcast packets aren’t sent from the PC through the VPN or are lost somewhere. It looks tricky to configure, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Publish Non-Web Server Protocols

[image: Publish Non-Web Server Protocols]

Rule name

[image: Rule name]

Your external NIC internet IP address ... not a google dns server )))

[image: Your external NIC internet IP address]

Create a new protocol

[image: Create a new protocol]

WOL: 7 and 9 UDP port ... I add TCP - paranoid mode on.

[image: WOL: 7 and 9 UDP port]

select WOL protocol

[image: select WOL protocol]

view ... WOL

## Not set External network. Create corporate network at Your IP address!

[image: view ... WOL]

Good luck

Comment: Which if my addresses should be entered at **Your external NIC internet IP address**? The address of the VPN adapter varies for each RAS dial in.

Comment: @harper ISA external address 83.26.4.139

Comment: This is the EXTERNAL address, The Internet. Wake-on-LAN packets can be sent by any node in the Internet. I don't plan to accept packets from the public Internet. It should be tunneled through Virtual Privat Network, shouldn't it?

Comment: @harper Yes, change `External` network to `VPN Clients` and additional create allow rule WOL protocol to `VPN Clients`, `Internal` and `Local Host`